# C++ — template vs typedef based class hierarchy

Tags: c++, templates, numbers, typedef

I am writing a library for efficient number processing. I have to support different types of numbers — `double`, `complex`, or even `custom_matrix` maybe. For performance reasons I've decided to compile separate library file for each number kind, so that compiler may use aggressive optimizations for arithmetic operations and function calls. Now I have two options — either to write template classes with parameter `number_type`, e.g.

```
template <typename valueType>
class Worker {
    valueType process(valueType value);
};
```

or to `typedef` number kind in project-wide header file, e.g.

```
in 'project.hpp':

namespace myProject {
    typedef double valueType;
}

in 'worker.hpp':

#include "project.hpp"

namespace myProject {
    class Worker {
        valueType process(valueType value);
    };
}
```

Personally I can't accept either way: template-based code is driving me insane with tons of redundant `template` and `typename` keywords, meanwhile typedef-based code can't be compiled in single library file (linking fails because of duplicate names), so I can't use different number types in one program.

So the question is: am I missing something? Is there a better/cleaner way to accomplish my task?

EDIT: I have to use `double` and `complex` code in one application at the same time.

EDIT2: Okay, to make things clear: I'm developing an arithmetic expression parsing engine for iOS app. Therefore I'm limited to C/C++/Objective-C, and the performance is crucial.

Also, I feel comfortable in using templates in common circumstances. In my situation all my source files are full of angle brackets and `template`/`typename` keywords. It's simply annoying and distracts me from writing stuff that matters.

I guess I'll use templates, since there is no better solution as far as I can see.

Comment: If you can't "accept" templates than you shouldn't be using C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the templates. If you insist on doing the absolute maximum amount of work at compile time instead of at run time, and your language of choice is C++, you will use template programming.

It's a mess of less-than and greater-than signs, confusing error messages, and `typename` keywords (plus don't get me started on explicit instantiations when you don't want to define your whole class in the header!), but it's the mess we've got.

EDIT: there is a third option, in the form of preprocessing - you could run the same code through the preprocessor twice, putting the symbols in a different namespace each time, to get the same effect as the `typedef` version without the symbol collisions.

Comment: @Stu: in conjunction with preprocessor-expanded names so you don't even notice the `>>` when you look at the source code...

Comment: AAAAH! Stop! Bad acid-like early Spirit library flashbacks! And people wonder why I veto C++ for production code...

Comment: @Stu: Instead of putting spaces between the closing > one could simply use C++11, where closing nested templates with >> (or more > depending on the nestin) is perfectly legal.

Comment: @Stu : "*And people wonder why I veto C++ for production code...*" I wouldn't wonder, I just wouldn't work with you. Being afraid of tools is downright silly.

Comment: @Grizzly: and as soon as there are production compilers around that fully comply with C++11, that would be a relevant statement.

Comment: @ildjarn: I am not afraid of any tools. I just think that C++ is becoming increasingly marginal. The hit in productivity and maintainability is very, very rarely worth it. In other news, I also refrain from performing home maintenance with a bazooka.

Comment: @Stu : The so-called "hit in productivity" is certainly subjective; that _you're_ less productive with C++ than some other languages is not a reflection on C++... Same goes for maintainability -- well-written C++ is no more or less difficult to maintain than well-written code in other languages (assuming actual familiarity with C++ and your toolchain).

Comment: @Stu: We don't have that many compilers which fully comply with C++03 either (one if memory serves), so I don't see a problem with using a partial implementation of C++11 for coding (as long as the supset is clearly defined, probably by the used compiler version).

Comment: @Borealid: brilliant idea about namespaces! I have already used `define`s for `namespace` wrap, so it's really easy now split code into subnamespaces with IDE. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ildjarn: fair enough. Do you have a toolchain that show the contents of a std::wstring in a tooltip, instead of std::wstring<yadda, yadda, std::char_traits<yadda, yadda, falling asleep, no useful information here>>?

Comment: @Stu : If you're referring to debuggers then VC++'s is nice (and handles that specific example fine), but agreed that debugging is one area where C++ does fall behind in general toolchain-wise. :-\

Comment: @ildjarn: No, it does not. An unmanaged std::string does still (as of VS2010) not show up properly. I was kind of hoping you'd tell me about the far superior tools elsewhere.

Comment: @Stu : I have VC++ 2010 SP1 open as we speak, and it displays the contents of `std::string` and `std::wstring` just fine. You may have an installation problem.

Comment: For certain values of "just fine", you are quite correct. But if you don't see a difference between C++ and C# debugger support, I don't know what to tell you. Bad venue for this, anyway.

Comment: @Stu : By "just fine" I mean that I see the C-string contents, just like in C#. "*if you don't see a difference between C++ and C# debugger support, I don't know what to tell you*" Sure I see a difference, it's just not important enough to justify my loss in productivity from switching away from C++. ;-]

Answer (score 4):

C++ people will tell you to use `template` without asking how your code is *actually* going to be used.

The key question here is: will your library ever be used with two different number types **at the same time**?

If the answer is "no" then templates would be a terrible choice. As you are well aware, templates are not easy to work with: they create more work for you, more work for the compiler, and more work for the IDE (that tries to parse them to provide autocompletion).

Just use a global `typedef`. You will save yourself a lot of headaches in the long run. By the way, [this is exactly what the Bullet physics library does](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/source/browse/trunk/src/LinearMath/btScalar.h#204).

Comment: Yes, I need to use `double` and `complex` in one application, that is the catch. Otherwise I would just stuck with `typedef`, as you suggested, and compile library to separate object files.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a better way. Threrefore if you need to use more then one type in any given program `templates` are basically the way to go. If you are sure that will never happen go ahead with `typedefs`, since they will be sufficient in that case and are easier to read/debug.

Of course if you write templates long enough they can become quite naturally up to the point where you use them even if they aren't strictly necessary (as in there would be other reasonable ways to solve the given problem). At least thats what happened to me